# If $X_t$ is right-continuous and adapted process, is $X_{t-}$ always predictable?

Tags: stochastic-processes

If $X_t$ is right-continuous and adapted process, is $X_{t-}$ always predictable? Or there are other conditions that must be satisfied? I've become a bit unsure due to the following example in "Introduction to Stochastic Calculus with Applications":

> Example 8.3: Right-continuous adapted processes may not be
>   predictable, even though they can be approached by left-continuous
>   processes, for example, $X_\epsilon(t)= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}
> > {X((t+\epsilon)−)}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is right-continuous with finite left limits (i.e. it is càdlàg) and adapted, then $(X_{t-})_{t\geq 0}$ is left-continuous and adapted and hence it is predictable.

I'm pretty sure you need the left limits to be finite in order to justify that $X_{t-}$ is finite.